# Ошибка при завершении цикла

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

есть массив :

```
print_r($data['AdvertData']['subCategory']);
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [seo] => dictaphones
        [id_category] => 124
        [title] => Диктофоны
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [seo] => audio
        [id_category] => 122
        [title] => Аудио
    )
 )
```

я создаю новый массив и наполняю его пробегаясь по верхнему и обращаясь к ячейке `[id_category]`

```
$data['subSelects'] = array();
$mainCategory = $data['AdvertData']['mainCategory'];
$i = 0;           
foreach ($data['AdvertData']['subCategory'] as $k => $v) {
    $i++;
    $data['subSelects'][$i] = $this->app->AdvertsModel->Selects($mainCategory, $v['id_category']);
    $data['subSelects'][$i]['parent'] = $data['AdvertData']['subCategory'][$k++]['id_category'];
    $mainCategory = $data['AdvertData']['subCategory'][$k++]['id_category'];
}
```

где `mainCategory` исходый самый первый id который про мере прохождения цикла меняется.
(как я понимаю) на последней итерации цикла выдается ошибка:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
```

я не могу ее исправить, пробовал разные проверки существования или на пустоту последнего ключа массива (`[$k++]`) не моиогло...

Comment: За место переменной i и k++ используйте просто k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $a++  Постфиксный инкремент   Возвращает значение $a, **затем** увеличивает $a на единицу.
>   http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php

Таким образом на первой итерации ваш пример превращается:

```
$k = 0 //из цикла foreach
$i = 1 // поскольку в первой строке цикла делаете инкремент $i++

// здесь $k++ возвращает 0, поскольку $k++ ПОСТинкрементный оератор
$data['subSelects'][1]['parent'] = $data['AdvertData']['subCategory'][0]['id_category'];

// после первого инкремента $k++ $k превращается в 1
$mainCategory = $data['AdvertData']['subCategory'][1]['id_category'];
```

ошибка вылетает на втором шаге цикла, поскольку:

```
$k = 1 //из цикла foreach
$i = 2 // поскольку в первой строке цикла делаете инкремент $i++

// здесь $k++ возвращает 1, поскольку $k++ ПОСТинкрементный оератор
$data['subSelects'][2]['parent'] = $data['AdvertData']['subCategory'][1]['id_category'];

// после инкремента $k++ в предыдущей строке $k превращается в 2 и вызывает ошибку
// Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
$mainCategory = $data['AdvertData']['subCategory'][2]['id_category'];
```

**Решение**: как вам советовали в первом комментарии, не использовать `$i`, `$i++`, `$k++`, а везде вместо них подставить `$k`, поскольку она итак итерируется в цикле `foreach`

Comment: дело в том что размер массива приведенного выше может быть и размером до 4х, т.е. неограниченный, мне в цикле нужно выбрать из этого массива элемент который находится в ячейке [$k+1]['id_category'] чтоб я мог отправить его как $mainCategory для выбора из базы в строке $this->app->AdvertsModel->Selects($mainCategory, $v['id_category']); и получается что на последней итерации массива  [$k+1]['id_category'] элемента не существует, поэтому и выходит эта ошибка! если я уберу ++ тогда последний массив  $data['subSelects'][$i-n] не будет заполнен! но кажется, можно через for и уменьшить кол-во i на 1

Comment: `if(key_exists(ключ, массив)) {}`

Comment: я может не верно делаю, но ошибку это не исправляет, не помогает, она все равно есть

Comment: @privetsh добавьте к своему вопросу результат `var_dump($data)`, а так же желаемый результат, который хотите получить

Comment: дамп вверху, а делается такой вывод из базы чтоб заполнить один массив другими т.е. есть главная категория и затем выбираются все дочерние категории этой главной